# Using custom target with CMake and CPack

Tags: cmake, cpack

In my CMake file I have somewhere :

```
add_custom_target(meta ALL COMMAND echo "Hello world")
```

Also somewhere CPack is included:

```
include (CPack)
```

Now when I run

```
make package
```

the command will be called twice. Once when CMake works, once when CPack works. 
This is just a sample but I can't provide dependencies for this command cause there are too many.

How can I run external command once during build procedure and don't call it during cpack?

Comment: According to [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_target.html), a custom target is "*always considered out of date*". So, the target is built whenever CMake is run. Because CPack executes CMake internally, the target is run during CPack too. If you want *COMMAND* to execute once, use `add_custom_command` instead. `I can't provide dependencies for this command cause there are too many.` - If you cannot describe, when commands should be executed, what do you expect from CMake?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Internally CPack calls make all and than make install. I'm not really sure why it's required to be run twice because theoretically "make install" literally runs make all as well.